# Beanstalkd Queue either fails or runs infinitely

Tags: laravel, beanstalkd

I am using a Beanstalkd queue to deploy jobs in my Laravel 5.3 application.  I use Laravel Forge to administer the server.

I have one of two scenarios that occur:

1) I set a max number of attempts, which causes every job pushed to the queue to be placed on the failed jobs table - even if its task is completed successfully, resulting in this exception on the jobs table:

```
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: A queued job has been attempted too many times. The job may have previously timed out
```

And this in my error log:

```
Pheanstalk\Exception\ServerException: Server reported NOT_FOUND
```

2) If I remove the max attempts, the jobs run successfully but in an infinite loop.

I am assuming that I am not removing these jobs from the queue properly and so in scenario #1 the job is failing because just wants to keep running.

My controller pushes my job to the queue like this:

```
  Queue::push('App\Jobs\UpdateOutlookContact@handle', ['userId' => $cs->user_id, 'memberId' => $member->id, 'connection' => $connection]);
```

Here is the handle function of my job:

```
 public function handle($job, $data)
{
    Log::info('Outlook syncMember Job dispatched');

    $outlook = new Outlook();
    $outlook->syncMember($data['userId'], $data['memberId'], $data['connection']);
    $job->delete();
}
```

Here is a picture of my queue configuration from the Laravel Forge admin panel. I am currently using the default queue.   If "Tries" is changed to ANY, the jobs succeed but run in an infinite loop.
[image]

How do I properly remove these jobs from the queue?

Comment: Laravel would release the job again into the queue if the job failed. So your job has some issues that is being released again and again. I suggest to put your code into try catch and log the exception in job class and put it here

Comment: Also why you push the job with this syntax? you can create job class and extend from laravel job class and then push this class into queue with laravel dispatcher. like `dispatch()` helper

Comment: And please tell me that how many listener are here to listen for queues?